# glGetSubroutineIndex выбрасывает исключение

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

Функция `GL40.glGetSubroutineIndex(pId, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "one");` выбрасывает исключение:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
>       at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
>       at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL40.glGetSubroutineIndex(GL40.java:516)

не пойму почему, видеокарта поддерживает 4.5 шейдеры. Кто знает в чем дело?

Comment: Драйвера обновляли?

Comment: Обновлял, попробовать может их удалить?

Comment: Какая у вас видеокарта, назовите точную модель? Убедитесь, что вывод OpenGL идет именно через нее (а не встроенную, например)

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650 Ti
у меня материнская плата без встроенной видеокарты

Comment: Я не знаю что мне делать, не могу продолжать обучение Opengl без этой функции

Comment: Попробуйте обновить lwjgl и `GL40.java`. Не знаю, чем вам еще помочь